# Delete record from HTML table if checkbox is selected in Python

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, html-table

I'm making a flask webpage which dynamically generates an HTML table from a database, and a checkbox for each record beside it. I want the user to select multiple records and delete them all at once, but I can't seem to figure out how to know which records are selected.
The code for the html table:

```
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="col-md-1">Delete</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-md-5">Device Name</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-md-6">Device MAC</th>
            </tr>
            {% for row in data %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{row .index}}"
                           value={{row .index}}{% if row .like== 1 %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}>
                    {{row .like}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{row[0]}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{row[1]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </thead>
        </table>
```

I was thinking about using the requests.form way of getting the 'checked' value, but it's not on a form, so how should I access this? And how do I do this for every record in the table, so I can delete them from the database?

Edit:

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Add':
                devAdd = [request.form['addDN'], request.form['addMAC']]
                error = addDevice(devAdd)
                return render_template('index.html', 
                errorAdd=error,data=loadDB())
            else:
                #Delete
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', data=loadDB())
```

The `if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Add':` part is another button that adds a record to the table, so the code for the delete process needs to be in the `else: #Delete`
part.
However, the table is not part of the form, so should I create its own form? And will it cause conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your python code as well? Depending on your python code, I think a clean way to do this might be to:

1. Create a form
2. Append a select field's value (maybe flask wtform) with the row_indices (from checkbox (True/False) -- JS might be useful here.
3. Retrieve those indices back from the POST request sent with the form submission
4. Drop the rows from your table based on the indices
5. Redirect back to this route that you're showing us in the HTML (basically a refresh with the updated table).

Comment: Also I don't know anything about JS so that is not an option.